# XSLT transform moving namespace

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have a XML posted to a WebService and I am having problems because it expects other xml format. 
I need transform the next xml adding xmlns:ans="http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/tiss/schemas and removing the namespace from solicitacaoProcedimentoWS node.

Some help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Luiz

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <solicitacaoProcedimentoWS xmlns="http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/tiss/schemas">
      <cabecalho>
        <identificacaoTransacao>
          <tipoTransacao>SOLICITACAO_PROCEDIMENTOS</tipoTransacao>
          <sequencialTransacao>k1</sequencialTransacao>
        </identificacaoTransacao>
      </cabecalho>
      <hash>393d3f1e310f3385ad0398dd9b65dc4a</hash>
    </solicitacaoProcedimentoWS>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I´d like to transform to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ans="http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/tiss/schemas"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ans:solicitacaoProcedimentoWS>
          <ans:cabecalho>
            <ans:identificacaoTransacao>
              <ans:tipoTransacao>SOLICITACAO_PROCEDIMENTOS</ans:tipoTransacao>
              <ans:sequencialTransacao>k1</ans:sequencialTransacao>
            </ans:identificacaoTransacao>
          </ans:cabecalho>
          <ans:hash>393d3f1e310f3385ad0398dd9b65dc4a</ans:hash>
        </ans:solicitacaoProcedimentoWS>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: What's the difference - other than cosmetics - between the input and the output?

Comment: Hi, There is not difference, but the webservice doesn´t accept if I don´t transform the xml format. I can´t change the webservice beacuse is not mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XSLT 2.0 stylesheet should do what you require:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
                xmlns:ans="http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/tiss/schemas">

  <!-- identity transformation - keep everything the same except when overridden -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- add an extra NS declaration to the document element -->
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:namespace name="ans" select="'http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/tiss/schemas'"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- use a prefixed name for any element in the namespace
       http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/tiss/schemas -->
  <xsl:template match="ans:*">
    <xsl:element name="ans:{local-name()}" namespace="http://www.ans.gov.br/padroes/tiss/schemas">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the real problem is with the service you're talking to - as you're aware, both versions of the file have all the same elements in all the same namespaces, so should be treated the same by any namespace-aware XML processor.  If they care about the use of specific prefixes in this way then they're probably not using a proper namespace-aware XML parser, and who knows what other aspects of the XML specifications they're ignoring or abusing.  If they require the body elements to be named with an `ans:` prefix, does that mean they also require the envelope to use the `SOAP-ENV:` prefix?  At least one SOAP toolkit I've used in the past uses `soap:` for this namespace instead of `SOAP-ENV:`...

---

If you're limited to XSLT 1.0 then you can't use `<xsl:namespace>` to create arbitrary namespace bindings, instead try something like

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/namespace::ans" />
```

to copy the namespace declaration from the stylesheet document itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your xslt works great. The  body content prefix is required but the envelope prefix is free.

Comment: @LuizAlves glad to help. On Stack Overflow, when you get an answer that solves your problem it's polite to mark it _accepted_ (by clicking the tick mark to the left)

Comment: Sorry, Mr Ian Roberts. I just did it. I am a newbie on Stack Overflow.